# How can I express the concept "There's nothing of which I'm absolutely sure" in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, translation, grammar

Scientists and philosophers have at various times been quoted as saying: 
"**There's nothing of which I'm absolutely sure**" or "**I'm not absolutely sure of anything**". (Richard Feynman, for example.)

How can this logical concept be expressed in Chinese?

I've made a first attempt below:

**對任何事情我都沒有絕對的把握.**

For some reason the above translation "feels" unsatisfactory (though, that might just be due to my undeveloped "語感").

Are there any clearer ways to express this logical concept in Chinese?

Comment: It sounds a little official, but still, perfect for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) (对)任何事情我都没有绝对的把握.

There is nothing wrong in this sentence, but it focuses on personal belief, a little bit inclining to the speaker's subjectiveness.

If we want to state something that describes a general belief, which focuses more on objectiveness, then we can say:

> 2) (对)任何事情 **我们** 都没有绝对的把握.
>
> 3) (对)什么事 **我们** 都 **不可能有** 绝对的把握.

Sentence 2 generalizes the idea expressed in sentence 1 by replacing 我 with 我们. 我们 covers not only the speaker, but also the readers and listeners.

Sentence 3 makes it even stronger, which emphasizes on the impossibility of having, while in sentence 2 没有 just describes the fact of not having.

Note: 任何事情 in sentence 2 is same as 什么事  in setence 3, no differences at all, they are interchangable.

Answer (score 2):

Colloquial:

> 我什么事情都不确定 Wǒ shénme dōu bù quèdìng

I'm not sure of anything...

Answer (score 2):

In Chinese, they will say '凡事我都没有十足的把握'，and '我能确定的就是凡事我都不确定' to enhance mood. Another alike saying is ' I know nothing except the fact of my ignorance', '我所知道的就是我一无所知'.